# In series RLC circuit, does decreasing the capacitance value really make the circuit more capacitive circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

This seems very counter intuitive to me. How can decreasing the capacitance value make the circuit more capacitive ? The math tells me so :

If $C$ decreases then $X_c = \dfrac{1}{\omega C}$ increases, so the circuit becomes more capactive.

[image]

But I've heard that factories that use heavy motors have a large $X_L$. For this reason they need to increase $X_C$ so that $X_L = X_C$. To increase $X_C$ they seem to "add" capacitors. But adding capacitors actually decreases $X_C$ right ? $X_C \propto \dfrac{1}{C}$. How does this work ?

---

Definitions :
$X_C\gt X_L$  : more capacitive circuit

$X_L\gt X_C$  : more inductive circuit

Comment: Also when $C=0$, we have $X_c = \infty$, does this mean the circuit is more capacitive when the capacitance is $0$ ? Hmm..

Comment: They might be adding capacitors in series. Thats the only possible way to increase capacitive reactance at constant frequency.

Comment: Yup, the larger a capacitance, the _weaker_ a capacitor is. Weird but true. It’s defined backwards relative to everything else.

Comment: Be careful with your definitions - since [reactance is the imaginary part of impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance#Reactance), $Z = R + jX$, capacitive reactance is *negative*.

Comment: Also, note that in this series RLC circuit, the total impedance is either inductive (positive imaginary part), resistive (zero imaginary part), or capacitive (negative imaginary part).

Comment: Given this, an impedance that is capacitive (negative imaginary part) becomes *more* capacitive as the capacitive reactance *decreases* (becomes more negative).